# Problems on Mobile Version

Tags: css, menu, toggle

I´m having one issue at my 720x1240 version of my responsive mobile website (both css and html issues).

1. the top of my site is creating an unwanted vertical scroll inside of it´s div (possibly NEWS_MOBILE div)! I can´t figure out why...
2. My Toggle Menu opens from left to right in a bizarre diagonal trajectory and don´t fill the whole screen. I´d like it to fall down vertically and fill the screen 100% like most pages do.
3. I want to close my div Menu by clicking the links.
4. And I also want to discover why my CSS code margins don´t obey me with precision for the widths =(

Below I will give you my HTML and CSS Codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>LeatherJacks || Official Website</title>


<!-- FAV ICON LOAD -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="07_FAVICON\favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="07_FAVICON\favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />



<!--CSS LOAD 1920px-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="01_Responsive_1920px.css">




<!-- META TAGS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 1368px)" href="02_Responsive_1368px.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 1000px)" href="03_Responsive_1000px.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 816px)" href="04_Responsive_MOBILE.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 720px)" href="05_Responsive_MOBILE_720.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 360px)" href="06_Responsive_MOBILE_360x640.css">






<!--HTML-->

<body>

    <div id="TUDO_MOBILE">




<!-- NAVBAR MENU -->


  <div id="Menu_Mobile">

      <img src="03_Botões\04_WebSite_Mobile\LeatherLogo.png">


     <button type="button" class="Menu_Mobile_toggle" data-menu-mobile-toggle="">
      <span></span>
     </button>





<div id="Menu">

            <a href="#NEWS_MOBILE">NEWS</a>
            <a href="#Tudo_Shows_MOBILE">SHOWS</a>
            <a href="#Tudo_Music_MOBILE">MUSIC</a>
            <a href="#Tudo_Video_MOBILE">VIDEO</a>
            <a href="#Tudo_Merch_MOBILE">MERCH</a>
            <a href="#Tudo_Contact_MOBILE">CONTACT</a>

        <ul>
           <li><a href="https://facebook.com/leatherjacksofficial" target="_blank">
           <img src="03_Botões\02_WebSite\02_Facebook_Btn.png" width="13" height="23"/></a></li>



           <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeufhZW3V2aFHp4Syqd85Dg" target="_blank">
           <img src="03_Botões\02_WebSite\03_YouTube_Btn.png" width="20" height="21"></a></li>



           <li><a href="https://instagram.com/maucorleatherjacks" target="_blank">
           <img src="03_Botões\02_WebSite\04_Instagram_Btn.png" width="23" height="23" /></a></li>



           <li><a href="https://twitter.com/leatherjacksgo" target="_blank">
           <img src="03_Botões\02_WebSite\05_Twitter_Btn.png" width="20" height="22" /></a></li>



           <li><a href="https://maucorleatherjacks.tumblr.com" target="_blank">
           <img src="03_Botões\02_WebSite\06_TumblR_Btn.png" width="10" height="21" /></a></li>



           <li><a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/2dZQJyKb2RNAltV18ffumG" target="_blank">
           <img src="03_Botões\02_WebSite\07_Spotify_Btn.png" width="18" height="22" /></a></li>



           <li><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/br/album/the-lost-arks-of-rock-and-roll/id1225814414" target="_blank">
           <img src="03_Botões\02_WebSite\08_iTunes_Btn.png" width="15" height="22" /></a></li>

         </ul>

       </div>




   </div>









<div id="NEWS_MOBILE">

    <div id="Wrapper_News">

     <div id="News_1"><header align="left">


   <!--MANCHETE_1-->


  <h1>NEW WEBSITE</h1>
   </header>



  <!--CHAMADA - 1-->
  <p align="left">

  <!--TEXTO - NEWS 1-->

  LeatherJacks is finally debuting it´s New Website! <br> Check it out for more details here! <br /> <br /> 


      CONTINUE READING </p>



   </div><!--FIM DA DIV NEWS_1-->





  <div id="News_2">
    <header align="left">

     <!--MANCHETE_2-->
    <h1>DEBUT SHOW</h1>
    </header>





  <!--CHAMADA - 2--> 
    <p align="left">

    Check More about our Debut Show at Manifesto Pub! <br /> <br />

    CONTINUE READING </p>

    </div><!--FIM DA DIV NEWS_2-->






  <div id="News_3">
    <header align="left">




  <!--MANCHETE_3-->
  <h1>GET SOCIAL</h1>
  </header>





   <!--CHAMADA - 3-->  
  <p align="left">


  Follow us at Social Networks, <br /> stay tuned and be a Jacker with us! <br /> <br /> 

  CONTINUE READING </p>


  </div><!--FIM DA DIV NEWS_3-->

   <div id="ALL_NEWS">ALL NEWS</div><!--FIM DA DIV ALL NEWS-->

  </div>    <!-- FIM DO WRAPPER NEWS -->

</div>


















<div id="Tudo_Shows_MOBILE">

<div id="Container_Shows">

  <div id="Shows_Title">
   <img src="04_Imagens_WebSite\02_SHOWS\Elementos_Layout\Shows.png">
  </div> 


  <div id="Wrapper_Shows">
  <script charset="utf-8" src="https://widget.bandsintown.com/main.min.js"></script><a class="bit-widget-initializer" data-artist-name="LeatherJacks" data-display-local-dates="false" data-display-past-dates="true" data-auto-style="false" data-text-color="#FFFFFF" data-link-color="#F1C200" data-popup-background-color="#000000" data-background-color="#000000" data-display-limit="15" data-link-text-color="#000000"></a>
  </div>


  </div>

</div>













<div id="Tudo_Music_MOBILE">

 <div id="Title_Music">
  <img src="04_Imagens_WebSite\03_MUSIC\Elementos_Layout\Title_Shows.png">
 </div>

   <div id="Container_Music">
    <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/55KlGZCK0nlxsnlts8B8gj" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
   </div>

</div>












<div id="Tudo_Video_MOBILE">

<div id="Title_Video">
<img src="04_Imagens_WebSite\04_VIDEO\Elementos_Layout\Video_Title.png">
</div>


  <div id="Watch"><header><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeufhZW3V2aFHp4Syqd85Dg/videos" target="_blank">Watch Our Videos</a></header>
  </div>


 <div id="Dentro_Video">
   <video id="Video_BG" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
    <source src="04_Imagens_WebSite\04_VIDEO\Elementos_Layout\Video_BG_1.webm"> 
   </video>
   </div>

   <div id="Post_Video"></div>

 </div>













<div id="Tudo_Merch_MOBILE">

 <div id="Merch_Title">
 <img src="04_Imagens_WebSite\05_MERCH\Elementos_Layout\Merch_Title.png"></div>

  <div id="Merch_Content">COMING SOON!</div>

</div>














<div id="Tudo_Contact_MOBILE">

 <div id="Form" action="send.php" method="POST" name="email"> 

   <form>
     <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" required onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'First Name'">
     <br>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Last Name'">
     <br>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" required onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email'">
     <br>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" required onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Subject'">
     <br>
     <textarea type="text" placeholder="Your Message Here" name="message" required onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your Message Here'"></textarea>
     <br>
     <button type="submit" name="send">SEND</button>
     <br>

   </form>


     <div id="emails">

      <div id="tour">
      <p>For booking Tour and Gigs, please contact us at<br><p><a href="mailto:management@leatherjacksofficial.com" target="_top">management@leatherjacksofficial.com</a></p>
      </div>

      <div id="press">
      <p>For Press inquiries, please contact us at<br><p><a href="mailto:press@leatherjacksofficial.com" target="_top">press@leatherjacksofficial.com</a></p>
      </div>

     </div>

 </div>

</div>



























<!-- SCRIPTS -->



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>

<script>
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
    var the_id = $(this).attr("href");

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:$(the_id).offset().top
    }, 'slow');
    return false;
});
</script>



      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">

           $(document).ready(function(){
             $('.Menu_Mobile_toggle').click(function(){
             $('.Menu_Mobile_toggle').toggleClass('ativo');
             $("#Menu").toggle('.Menu_Mobile_toggle.ativo');
            });
           });

           $(document).click(function(e) {
             if ($(e.target).closest('.Menu_Mobile_toggle').length == 0) {
             $(".Menu_Mobile_toggle").removeClass('ativo');
            $("#Menu").hide();
           }
          });





      </script>





</body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
<style>


@font-face {
    font-family: "Bebas";
    src: url("06_Fonts/Bebas.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Bebas";
    src: url("06_Fonts/BEBAS__.TTF") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}





* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

html { 
   font-family:"Bebas", "Arial"; 
   font-size: 20px;
}



html, body { 
   margin:0; 
   overflow-x:hidden;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #000;
}



#TUDO_MOBILE {
    width: 720px;
    height: 7440px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#Menu_Mobile {

    width: 720px;
    height: 130px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1;
}


#Menu_Mobile img {      /*LEATHERJACKS LOGO  */
    max-width: 260px;
    max-height: 64px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 30%;
    clear: right;
    clear: left;
    cursor: auto;
}


.Menu_Mobile_toggle {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top:2px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    right: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #000;
    border:none;
}


.Menu_Mobile_toggle span {
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 7px;
    background: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left:10px;
    top: 42px;
    transition:0.3s;
}

.Menu_Mobile_toggle span:before {
    content: '';
    background: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: -30px;
    width:100%;
    height: 7px;
    transition:0.3s;

}

.Menu_Mobile_toggle span:after {
    content: '';
    background: #FFF;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top: 30px;
    width:100%;
    height: 7px;
    transition:0.3s;
    border:none;

}


.Menu_Mobile_toggle.ativo span {
    background: transparent;
}

.Menu_Mobile_toggle.ativo span:before {
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition:0.3s;
    height: 7px;

}

.Menu_Mobile_toggle.ativo span:after {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition:0.3s;
    height: 7px;

}



#Menu {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 720px;
    height: 1240px;
    background-color: #000; 
    margin-left: 50px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    line-height: 100px;
    clear: both;
}


#Menu_Links a:link {
    max-width: 360px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Bebas";
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 100px;
}

#Menu_Links ul { 
   margin: 0%;
   margin-top:0%;
   margin-left: 19%;
   padding:0%; 
   list-style-type:none;
}

#Menu_Links ul li { 
   padding: 20px;
   margin-top: 90px; 
   float:left;
}

#Menu_Links ul li a {   
   padding: 0 0 0 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

#Menu_Links img:link, #navbar_social img:visited {
    opacity:1;
}

#Menu_Links img:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
}





/* PÁGINA */





#NEWS_MOBILE {
   position: absolute; 
   width: 720px;
   height: 1240px;
   margin-top: 160px;
   margin-left: 0px;
   background-image: url("04_Imagens_WebSite/01_NEWS/01_Elementos_Layout/BG-News-720.jpg");
   background-size: 100%;
}

#Wrapper_News {
    width: 720px;
    height: 1240px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 30%;
    background-color: transparent;
}






/* NEWS SECTION */

#News_1 {
    background:none;
    width: 720px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#News_2 {
    background:none;
    width: 720px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-top: 120px;
}

#News_3 {
    background:none;
    width: 720px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top: 120px;
}

#News_1 header, #News_2 header, #News_3 header {
    font-family: "Bebas";
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #bf2d63;

}


#News_1 p, #News_2 p, #News_3 p {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size:12px;
    color: #FFF;
}

#ALL_NEWS {
    font-family: "Bebas";
    font-size:40px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    color:#FFF;
    opacity: 0.8;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    background-color: #000;
    background-color: transparent;
}

/*FIM DO NEWS SECTION */








/* SHOWS */

#Tudo_Shows_MOBILE {
    width:720px;
    height: 1248px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 958px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
}

#Container_Shows {
    max-width: 720px;
    max-height: 940px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 130px;
    position: absolute;
}

#Shows_Title {
    max-width: 220px;
    max-height:60px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 22%;

}

#Shows_Title img {
    max-width: 220px;
    max-height:60px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 25%;

}

#Wrapper_Shows {
    max-width: 720px;
    height: 894px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-top: 50px;

}


#Wrapper_Shows script {
    max-width: 720px;
    max-height: 894;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    margin-top: 80px;

}




/* FIM DAS DIVS DE SHOWS NO CSS */











/* CONTAINTER MUSIC */

#Tudo_Music_MOBILE {
    max-width:720px;
    max-height: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 12%;
    margin-top: 1910px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("04_Imagens_WebSite/03_MUSIC/Elementos_Layout/BG-Music-720.jpg");
    background-size: 100%
}


#Title_Music {
    max-width: 720px;
    max-height: 69px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 160px;
}


#Title_Music img {
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 54px;
    margin-left: 36%;

}

#Container_Music {
    max-width: 720px;
    max-height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#Container_Music iframe {
    max-width: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}




/* CONTAINER VIDEO */

#Tudo_Video_MOBILE {
    max-width: 720px;
    max-height: 894px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 14px;
    margin-top: 2737px;
    position: absolute;
}


#Dentro_Video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:-1;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-top: 130px;
}


#Dentro_Video video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    z-index:0;
    opacity: 0.7;
}


#Title_Video {
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 69px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-top: 140px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#Watch {
    width: 600px;
    height: 36px;
    margin-left: 24.8%;
    margin-top: 40%;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#Watch header {
    font-family: "Bebas";
    font-size: 380%;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#Watch header a:link, #Watch header a:visited {
    font-family: "Bebas";
    font-size: 60%;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


#Watch header a:hover {
    font-family: "Bebas";
    font-size: 60%;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 3.7px;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
    scale: (0.99, 0.99);
    text-decoration: none;
    /* color: #ff9b1a; */
    color: #f2237b;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#Watch header a:hover:after {
    font-family: "Bebas";
    font-size: 60%;
    color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#Post_Video {
    max-width: 720px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 463px;
    background-color: #000;
}




/* CONTAINER MERCH */

#Tudo_Merch_MOBILE {
    max-width: 720px;
    height: 894px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3610px;
    margin-left: 14%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#000;
}


#Merch_Content {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Bebas";
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-left: 50%;
}



#Merch_Title {
    max-width: 250px;
    max-height: 69px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 33%;
    margin-top: 160px;
}






/* CONTAINER CONTACT */



#Tudo_Contact_MOBILE {
    max-width: 720px;
    height: 960px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -4.5%;
    margin-top: 4480px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#000;
}


#Form {
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-top: 120px;
}

#Form input {
    max-width: 570px;
    width: 95%;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: "Bebas";
    font-size: 40px;
    font-color: #FFF;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}


#Form textarea {
    max-width: 570px;
    width: 95%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top:30px;
    font-family: "Bebas";
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    width: 570px;
    height: 180px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #000;
    resize: none;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}


#Form input, #Form textarea {
    color: red;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
}


#Form input::-webkit-input-placeholder,
#Form textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: initial;
}





#Form button {
    max-width: 591px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 68px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #4c0000;
    font-family: "Bebas";
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #FFF !important;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: -4px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#Form button:hover {
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    background-color: #c60000;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(0.99, 0.99);
    opacity: 1;
}


#emails {
    max-width: 720px;
    max-height: 450px;
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
    margin-left: -6%;
    margin-top: 60px;
    position: absolute;
}

#tour {
    font-family: "Bebas";
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 1920px;
    width: 100%;
}

#press {
    font-family: "Bebas";
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 1920px;
    width: 100%;
}


#tour a:link, #press a:link {
    color: #c60000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#tour a:hover, #press a:hover {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    letter-spacing: 1.94px;
}

#tour a:visited, #press a:visited {
    color: #c60000;
    text-decoration: none;
}



</style>
```

Where am I wrong? Please guys help me! =)

PS: The website works perfect at Desktop PC´s, Tablets, Ipads, etc... It´s going very responsive at big devices =)

But not mobile... =(

Thank you all very much!

---

now this is the script I got to make my X button comes back to the Burger shape when I click outside my Dropdown Menu...

How do I make the burger button come to it´s initial state (from X to ||| ) when I click on my Dropdown Menu links?

[image]

This is my script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

           $(document).ready(function(){
             $('.Toggle').click(function(){
             $('.Toggle').toggleClass('ativo');
             $("#Drop_Down").toggle('.Toggle.ativo');
            });
           });



           $(document).click(function(e) {
             if ($(e.target).closest('.Toggle').length == 0) {
             $(".Toggle").removeClass('ativo');
            $("#Drop_Down").hide();
           }
          });




      </script>
```

I need to make my toggle burger menu get back to it´s initial state when click the links. At html, I did `<a href="#" onclick="hide(mydiv)">` for my Dropdown Menu links, so the menu closes normally... But the Toggle is still in X shape.

when I click outside the menu or anywhere... It closes the dropdown menu and gets back to it´s initial state, as expected =)

---

I´m 90% on my website, but it´s out of place in my Moto G3... the 360x640 resolution is not centering my website...

What is happening, guys? =(

[Out of place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhfLE.png)

What could it be?

Thank you all !!!

Answer (score 0):

1. `#Tudo -> remove overlfow-x: hidden;`from CSS
2. use slideToggle() instead of toggle() in  your script

   http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/
3. Add script when you implement click action on links.

Example:

```
$('#Drop_Down a').click(function(){
    $('.Toggle').toggleClass('ativo');
    $("#Drop_Down").toggle('.Toggle.ativo');
});
```

4. Be more specific - which margin is not right? How should it look like? (some images? some jsfiddle code snippet where we can play with the example?)

Comment: Do I remove the "overflow-x:hidden;" from the 1920px css code or the 360px css code?

Comment: I still have only one problem: when I click my burger menu, my "dropdown menu" appears and the icon turns into the X shape... okay... 

So when I click anywhere, the "dropdown menu" closes and my burger menu returns to it´s initial state.

But when I click the links (I used "onclick = hide(dropdownmenu)"), my menu hides okay... But my toggle don´t get back to it´s initial burger shape...

what do I have to do, Adrian?

Thankssssssss =)